# Lambda notation in Rails. How is it used? What is the argument in the parenthesis inside a lambda in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

Say I have an `Order` model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :last_month, ->(object) { where(“publish_date > ?”, 1.month.ago) }
end
```

So, that's apparently how to define a scope in Rails. But what is the object inside that lambda parenthesis? If `object` represents the resulting AR collection...why does that make sense? What's going on behind the scenes? Why is a Proc needed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the object inside that lambda parenthesis?

The line is syntax sugar for this:

```
lambda { |object| where("publish_date > ?", 1.month.ago) }
```

The `object` value is an argument to the lambda.

> If object represents the resulting AR collection...why does that make sense?

As Sergio said, it represents additional args you can pass.

> What's going on behind the scenes? Why is a Proc needed here?

The proc is more of a forced solution to older problems. So when you used to define scopes like this:

```
scope :created_after, Time.now
```

Time.now would run immediately when the rails app booted. So it wouldn't re-evaluate Time.now each time you ran the scope. Lambda ensures your logic executes each time.

Comment: ah that's a thorough explanation as to why it's a a lambda/proc.

Comment: What about when used in a has_many like this:
`has_many :subclass_point_analytics, -> (object) { where("assessment_id = ?", object.assessment_id) }, :foreign_key => 'gid',  :dependent => :destroy`. What is `object`

Comment: Doesn't change from Segio's point. It's what ever arguments you pass to the scope when you call it in your controller/model.

Answer (score 3):

> If object represents the resulting AR collection

Nope, `object` represents a parameter to the scope. If you have this scope, for example:

```
class User
  scope :created_after, ->(timestamp) { where('created_at > ?', timestamp) }
end
```

then you can call it like this:

```
User.created_after(3.days.ago)
```